# Testing function with form as argument in Angularjs with Karma and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am using Angularjs+grunt+karma+jasmine. This is how I have wrote the function in my controller:

```
Vm.find = function(form){
 /* code lines */
};
```

and I have called the function with ng-click on the view side.

```
<form name="form">
<input/>
<input/>
<input/>
<button ng-click(Vm.find(form))></button>
</form>
```

Now I am stuck on how to call the function with the form as argument in the unit testing. I am using the below code in the **testing spec** file to fetch the template html. But don't know how to trigger the function.

```
html = templateCacheMock.get('modules/reports/partials/renewals/generate-renewals.htm');
    complied = angular.element(html);
    element = compileMock(complied)(scope);
    element.find('.find-btn').triggerHandler('click');
```

I am totally new to unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `ng-click`, the invoked function MUST be part of the `$scope` object. Therefore, the declaration should be:

```
$scope.Vm.find = function (...) {...};
```

Comment: What about the form argument?

Comment: You can use `ng-mode` to bind each input to a `$scope` element. Once this is done, Angular establishes a bi-directional binding between the JavaScript variables and the HTML elements. For instance, suppose that to one of the input fields you add `ng-model="first_name"`; within the JavaScript you will have a variable named `$scope.first_name` that will contain whatever was entered into the input field. Likewise, if you change the value of the variable within the JavaScript, the change will automatically be reflected into the HTML page.